# How to change size of leftbarbutton item?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I added a leftbarbutton image and change it size like this.

```
let homeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        homeButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash-logo_iso"), for: .normal)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: homeButton)
```

even chance width and  height, my navigation item look like this.
How can I change the size ? any advice or sample code please?

**my nav item looks like this now :**

[image: leftbarbuttonimage]

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution like this :**

```
 let homeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
        homeButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "splash-logo_iso"), for: .normal)
        //menu button custom view
        let leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width:24,height:24))
        leftView.addSubview(homeButton)

        //left uibarbutton
        let leftItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftView)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

Comment: Just that, or you can do the same with the storyboard. `I) UIView` __ `constraints` as `(leading, trailing, top, bottom) as (0,0,0,0) and height and width as 25, 25` `II) --> UIButton`..